# Will I be able to install apks on Android/Google TVs

Tags: android, android-tv

On this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/11/app-bundles-for-google-tv-and-android-tv.html) it is mentioned that starting from May 2023, Android/Google TV apps will only support app bundles (and not apks).
Does this mean that I won't be able to sideload (install manually an apk) directly into the TV?
Or does this only apply to apps installed through Google Play Store?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices can only install APKs. App bundles are used to **upload** an app to the Google Play Store. The Play Store uses it to generate optimized APKs for various device configurations so that users get a smaller APK.

The Google Play Store started to enforce a policy that new apps and updates need to be delivered as app bundles. However you can still install APKs manually on all of your android devices through 3rd party stores or manually.